# Configure Tensorflow for CPU using Java API

Tags: java, tensorflow, inference

I trying to play with the numbers for **intra_op_parallelism_threads** an **inter_op_parallelism_threads**. I use Tensorflow and Proto version 1.8.0 for Java.
I used the following code:

```
     ConfigProto config = ConfigProto.newBuilder()
                            .setInterOpParallelismThreads(44)
                            .setIntraOpParallelismThreads(44).build();

     outputs = model.session().runner().setOptions(config.toByteArray()).
                     feed("image_tensor", input).fetch("detection_scores").fetch("detection_classes").fetch("detection_boxes").fetch("num_detections").run();
```

When I run the a inference I get the following error:Timed out waiting for notification.
[image: Error]

Am I doing it wrong? Is there another approach?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same problem and here is my way out.

```
SavedModelBundle.loader("model_dir").withTags("tag").withConfigProto(config.toByteArray()).withXX().load();
```